# How to add zero on the left on a int field using java

Tags: java, parsing, if-statement, int, simpledateformat

i'm trying to compare a personalnumber with the current date to get the persons age.

The current problem is that if my personalnumber has a zero in it, it gets removed so i can't parse it.

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= personList.size(); i++) {

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String date = formatter.format(new Date());

            String temp = personList.get(i).getCPR();
            int year = Integer.parseInt((temp.substring(4, 6)));
            if (year < 20) {
                year += 2000;
            } else {
                year += 1900;
            }

            int month = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(2, 4));
            int day = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(0, 2));

            /*if (month if month don't start with zero){
                    add 0 to month on the left
                }
                    same goes for day*/


            String birthday = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

            LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(birthday);
            LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse(date);

            long age = date1.until(date2, ChronoUnit.YEARS);

            System.out.println(age);
        }
```

this is the error i'm getting

Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1995-1-13' could not be parsed at index 5

I want 1995-1-13 to read 1995-01-13

Comment: I would recommend to go through the simpledateformat java documentation and see which format suits your requirement.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

A quick fix for your code would be to change the birthday expression as shown below
 String birthday = String.format("%d-%02d-%02d",year,month,day);

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead Stick to the `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) that you are already using, and if you need, also `DateTimeFormatter` from this API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formatter you want is `"yyyy-M-d"` that will take care of both single digit and double digit `month` and `day` values:

```
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-d");
 String temp ="1995-1-13";

 LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(temp, formatter);
 long age = date1.until(LocalDateTime.now(), ChronoUnit.YEARS);
 System.out.println(age);
```

Output:

```
 24
```

This is as per the JDK [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> Number: If the count of letters is one, then the value is output using
>   the minimum number of digits and without padding. Otherwise, the count
>   of digits is used as the width of the output field, with the value
>   zero-padded as necessary.

Do not use the `SimpleDateFormat` classes if you are in Java 8+. I assumed you are on Java 8 as you used `LocalDate` classes. Also instead of using `String#substring` with hardcoded indexes to separate the date components use the  `DateTimeFormatter#ofPattern` to parse the `String` date into a `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need these two lines:

```
int month = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(2, 4));
int day = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(0, 2));
```

because you add those Integers again to string.

```
StringBuilder birthday = new StringBuilder();
birthday.append(year);
birthday.append("-");
birthday.append(temp.substring(2,4));
birthday.append("-");
birthday.append(temp.substring(0,2));
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(birthday.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Pass the date in YYYY-MM-dd format, i.e., 1995-1-15
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public void parseDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
    try {
        // Parsing and then formatting date using SimpleDateFormat object.
        String requiredDate = dateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(date));

        // Printing in the log
        Log.d("Parsed Date", requiredDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: One, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are poorly designed, long outdated and not recommended at all. Two, when I pass a date string of `1995-1-15` to your code, I get a `requiredDate` of `1995-01-01`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming a Danish *personnumer* (person number, “social security number”) of the format

```
ddmmyycxxg
```

For example for a woman born on August 24, 2001, the number might be

```
2408018314
```

The digits mean:

- `dd`: day of month of birth
- `mm` month of birth
- `yy` year of birth
- `c` code for century of birth; for historic reasons it has come to mean:

  - 0–3: 1900–1999
  - 4 or 9: 1937–2036
  - 5–8 Either 1858–1899 or 2000–2057
- `xx` any digits
- `g` code for gender: even for women, odd for men

Or in code:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter1858 = formatterWithBaseYear(1858);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter1900 = formatterWithBaseYear(1900);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter1937 = formatterWithBaseYear(1937);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter2000 = formatterWithBaseYear(2000);

    String personnummer = "2408018314";

    char centuryCode = personnummer.charAt(6);
    String birthDateString = personnummer.substring(0, 6);
    LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    switch (centuryCode) {
    case '0':
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
        // 1900 - 1999
        dateOfBirth = LocalDate.parse(birthDateString, formatter1900);
        break;

    case '4':
    case '9':
        // 1937 - 2036
        dateOfBirth = LocalDate.parse(birthDateString, formatter1937);
        break;

    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
        // 1858 - 1899 or 2000 - 2057
        dateOfBirth = LocalDate.parse(birthDateString, formatter1858);
        if (dateOfBirth.getYear() > 1899) {
            dateOfBirth = LocalDate.parse(birthDateString, formatter2000);
            assert dateOfBirth.getYear() >= 2000 && dateOfBirth.getYear() <= 2057 : dateOfBirth;
        }
        break;

    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not a valid digit: " + centuryCode);
    }

    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Copenhagen"));
    if (dateOfBirth.isAfter(today)) {
        System.out.println("This person was born in the future??");
    }

    long ageInYears = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(dateOfBirth, today);
    System.out.println(ageInYears);
```

I am using the following auxiliary method for building the four formatters:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter formatterWithBaseYear(int year) {
    return new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("ddMM")
            .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 2, year)
            .toFormatter();
}
```

The snippet prints:

> 18

I saw the following issues with your code:

- It doesn’t seem to take into account that a person may be more than 100 years old. It seems to assume a birth year from 1920 through 2019. This will also cause trouble if you try it with a newborn baby in just 4 months from now (birth year will be 2020).
- You were trying to use the notoriously troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` and the likewise outdated `Date` class.
- You are parsing day, month and year separately. It’s better to leave the entire parsing to a `DateTimeFormatter`. It will parse everything at once and also provide validation that we are getting a valid date.
- Converting your parsed number back into a new string and parsing that string once more is overcomplicating things (and was also the reason for your trouble with parsing one-digit numbers back). Just avoid all of that.
- For getting today’s date just use `LocalDate.now(yourTimeZone)`.  No reason for any formatting or parsing.

**Link:** [Personnummeret i CPR-systemet](https://cpr.dk/media/17534/personnummeret-i-cpr.pdf) (The personnummer in the Central Person Register System) documenting the meaning of the digits (in Danish).